# PHP imagecreatetruecolour center image

Tags: php

I am trying to center an image to the middle of an

```
$thumbnail_gd_image = imagecreatetruecolor(600, 300);
```

command. If a user uploads an image that is 100x50 I generate a larger version to 600x300 with a white background. Now at the moment the actual image is placed in the top left corner. I would like this image in the middle of the 600x300 generated image.

On the other side, if a user uploads an image that is larger than 600x300 then I resize down to keep within those parameters.

I am building an image upload/cropping tool however the croppable area is always twice as wide as what it is high so I need the useable cropping area to be within 600x300 for any detailed cropping.

Can this be done? The center of a smaller than 600x300 image?

Thanks

EDIT:

Tried the below code but it didnt like it.

This is my code (Probably not the cleanest but it needs to be semi working quickly).

```
if($source_image_width < 600 && $source_image_height < 300){
    $x = (600 / 2) - ($source_image_width / 2);
    $y = (300 / 2) - ($source_image_height / 2);
}else if($source_image_width > 600){
    $x = 0;
    if($source_image_height < 300){
        $y = (300 / 2) - ($source_image_height / 2);
    }else{
        $y = 0; 
    }
}else if($source_image_height > 300){
    if($source_image_width < 600){
        $x = (600 / 2) - ($source_image_width / 2);
    }else{
        $x = 0;
    }
    $y = 0;
}else{
    $x = 0;
    $y = 0;
}
```

The above code puts a 400 wide x 800 high image slightly to the left of center (about 100px). The hight on any image works perfectly but just not the width.

Answer (score 2):

you could try:

```
$W = 600;
$H = 300;

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
list($w,$h) = getimagesize($filename);
$x = ($W / 2) - ($w/2);
$y = ($H / 2) - ($h/2);

$newIm = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
// i know I could have used a better function for this, but...
imagecopyresampled($newIm, $im, $x, $y, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

I didn't have to time to test it (sorry) but it should work, if it doesn't, just tell me, and I will debug it.

EDIT 1:

for large images, you must crop from it. All that you have to do might be just

```
$W = 600;
$H = 300;

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
list($w,$h) = getimagesize($filename);
$x = ($W / 2) - ($w/2);
$y = ($H / 2) - ($h/2);

$x = sqrt($x * $x);
$y = sqrt($y * $y);

$newIm = imagecreatetruecolor($new_w, $new_h);
// i know I could have used a better function for this, but...
imagecopyresampled($newIm, $im, $W > $w ? $x : 0, $W > $w ? $y : 0, $W > $w ? 0 : $x, $W > $w ? 0 : $y, $w, $h, $w, $h);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($thumb);
```

try it and let me know the result. Yet again, I didn't test it, it might fail in an epic manner.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. This works great for images that are smaller than 600x300 however for larger images it places them off center.

Comment: I have updated my answer for smaller and also for bigger picture, the concept was simple, you put the smaller image in center, or you put the "center" in the bigger image (cropping the rest). Check it out if you are interested.